# I received a message "cannot find symbol" but I already define in .xml file

Tags: java, android, mobile-application, android-developer-api, androidimageslider

Why am getting can not find the symbol? but I already defined "slider1" as a id. Therefore I clean the project and rebuild it again. But it does not work. How to solve that? I put the half of the code and an error was coming from
"sliderLayout = (SliderLayout)findViewById(R.id.slider1);"

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.daimajia.slider.library.Animations.DescriptionAnimation;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderTypes.BaseSliderView;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderTypes.TextSliderView;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.Tricks.ViewPagerEx;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
import com.moraspirit.moraspiritapp.about.AboutActivity;
import com.moraspirit.moraspiritapp.article.ArticleActivity;
import com.moraspirit.moraspiritapp.homemenu.HomeMenuAdapter;
import com.moraspirit.moraspiritapp.homemenu.HomeMenuItem;
import com.moraspirit.moraspiritapp.homemenu.OnItemClickListener;
import com.moraspirit.moraspiritapp.points.RankingActivity;
import com.moraspirit.moraspiritapp.sports.MatchActivity;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;



public class NewHomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener, ViewPagerEx.OnPageChangeListener {

    RecyclerView homeTiles;
    List<HomeMenuItem> menuItems;

    SliderLayout sliderLayout;
    HashMap<String,String> Hash_file_maps ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_home);

        Hash_file_maps = new HashMap<String, String>();

        sliderLayout = (SliderLayout)findViewById(R.id.slider1);
```

Here is the activity_new_home.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".NewHomeActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textHome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo1"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
            android:id="@+id/slider1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textHome"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/home_tiles"
        android:layout_width="401dp"
        android:layout_height="382dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slider1"
        android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/slider1">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the pic about the error which am getting.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faDNK.jpg)

Comment: try to restart IDE

Comment: File-->Invalidate caches/ restart

Comment: Still am getting that message

Comment: Please post the xml of activity_new_home

Comment: I posted it above

Comment: the code looks fine, can you post a pic of the error just to double-check?

Comment: I uploaded that pic

Comment: Please help me to solve the issue